# Translate View footer

Tags: views, i18n-l10n

I'm trying to translate a link in footer on my views .
the code is :

```
<?php
$link = l(t('Click to view all the writing categories'), 'somewhere', array('attributes' => array('class' => array('read-latest'))));
print $link;
?>
```

The problem is after tranlate it from `admin/config/regional/translate` .
the output is `<div>` no link and no `<a>` tag .
Any idea ?

Comment: Make a var_dump of `$link`. Is there any error in watchdog? Did you try to just print the translated string? Did it work?

Comment: @Paul how can i print the translated string ?  
THX anyway

Comment: Instead of `print $link;` try `print t('YOUR UNTRANSLATED TEXT');` first. Does this return the translated text? What's the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by this module [String Overrides](https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) you can translate strings .
That's it